# is a double sided layer a thing in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm simulating a page being turned in a book. I'm using After Effects.
An illustrator file is imported into After Effects and that file contains a few layers.
One layer represents a page and another layer represents the rest of the book.
The problem I have faced is that when the page/layer is turned the "back" of the page/layer isn't opaque. Is there a way to make the back side of a layer in Illustrator plain white or black?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like *all digital images*, Illustrator files only have one side. There is no "back" to any layer or file.

Illustrator files have transparent backgrounds. Even though, by default, they **appear** white in Illustrator. You can turn on the Transparency Grid in Illustrator (View menu) to see the *actual* transparency.

If you want artboards/layers to be opaque rather than transparent, you need to **add a filled rectangle** the size of the artboard/layer.

---

Be aware that if using the "Simulate Paper" option in Illustrator's document setup a white rectangle won't do any good. One needs to **turn off** "Simulate Paper" option and use a rectangle at the bottom of the layer stack for any color/texture desired.